# Install package in RStudio got permission denied

Tags: rstudio

I was trying to install rattle package in RStudio in Mac but had this problem.

```
The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/private/var/folders/jg/725mdnns39z944j_s1q2hwg40000gn/T/Rtmpe2a0uF/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Warning messages:
1: In file.create(f.tg) :
  cannot create file '/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.3_1/lib/R/doc/html/packages.html', reason 'Permission denied'
2: In make.packages.html(.Library) : cannot update HTML package index
```

I tried the following methods:

**One**

I used the following lines to change folder permission

```
ls -ld /usr/local/Cellar
sudo chmod a+w /usr/local/Cellar
```

The folder permission is changed as follows:

`drwxrwxrwx 118 dph admin 3776 Apr 23 00:40 /usr/local/Cellar`

But the problem still not solved.

**Two**

I found `.libPaths()` to check lib directory and change that folder's permission, too. It doesn't work.

**Three**

I used `.libPaths("/home/rlib")` to change installation place. Doesn't work.

**Four**

I moved to the terminal rather than the RStudio console to install the package. As I suspect RStudio may have no right to access folders. When installing, the terminal asked me allowing the terminal to access folders? But even choosing yes doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is correct. One comment in the RStudio forum said we need to open the application on administration mode. And I found in Mac, you can do this:

```
cd /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/
sudo ./MacOS
```

And it is working!!